# Suitable verb form in the past tense sentence

Tags: grammar, tenses, past-tense

There's the next sentence: *"I saw Mr Brown ..... the building at two o'clock."*

Which option would be the most appropriate to put in and why ? I really want to put in "was leaving", but there's no such option.

leave / to leave / having left

Comment: Since there's no 'was leaving' option, which do you think is the most suitable out of the options?

Comment: @marcellothearcane i have no idea. i would choose 'having left'... 'to leave' - certainly no, infinitive there is not needed. 'leave' - hmm, may be 'saw' indicates past time and there's no necessity to indicate this time again, but (he\she\it) need to have ['s] ending... but for the last option I don't have any thoughts, so would choose it in the exam

Comment: I think you're right in that saw already indicates past tense, but I'm not sure if that is correct. Idiomatically 'leave' sounds right to me.

Comment: Also you might be interested in [ell.stackexchange.com](https://ell.stackexchange.com) for english learners :)

Comment: @marcellothearcane you're right, but why ? ... I'm sorry that for me it doesn't sound idiomatically :(

Comment: I don't know why, unfortunately! I"m a native speaker and that is what sounds right to me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Leave* is indeed the correct option. However, there is also some intuition behind this seemingly strange usage. Let's first clarify that *was leaving* is actually incorrect, so even if that option was given you still couldn't use it. To see this, we replace *Mr.Brown* by *him*. So we get *I saw him...*. Now we can see that the sentence that starts with *him* actually has no subject at all! So *was* is wrong since Mr.Brown isn't the subject anywhere at all!

However, we know that each sentence must have a subject. And yet, there is none here. In fact, this sentence is gramatically wrong since the modern English language doesn't allow for such constructions. The exact name of this construction of a sentence is **Accusativus cum Infinitivo**, and it is widely used in ancient languages such as Greek or Latin. What happens here is that the object (*him*) is taken to be the subject and the infinitive (*leave*) is taken to be the primal verb. So note that *leave* isn't a verb in the present tense but the full infinitive.

All in all, this is a rather antique construction that one can expect to find in ancient texts. So even though this usage might seem idiomatic, it was a common way of speaking a few thousand years ago.

Comment: great, thank you! also, I found out that it's called 'complex object' in modern grammar